# Rounding UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make my tableView look like this one:

[image]

and I have problem with it. My right corners round only after I tap on the cell. When view appears it looks like this:

[image]

and like this after tap:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
      func round(corners: UIRectCorner, withRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        let mask = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = self.bounds
        shape.path = mask.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = shape
      }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    if numberOfRows(in: indexPath.section) == 1 {
      cell.round(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight, .topLeft, .topRight], withRadius: 8)
    } else {
      if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.round(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], withRadius: 8)
      }
      if indexPath.row == numberOfRows(in: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        cell.round(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], withRadius: 8)
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: try move these code to `willDisplayCell`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because when you round your cell first time, it is not drawn on any superview, thus it's frame is unknown. Try to round the corners in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
```

Also, I highly recommend you DO NOT round the cell itself, instead, add background view to the cell, make cell's background color clear (cell's content view's as well), and make the rounded corners to that view. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try background view thing, maybe it will resolve some other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom UITableviewcell  for your design . And take cornerradius = 2 for tableviewcell Parentview.

Comment: I already have custom cell, but it's pretty simple (just 2 iboutlets). And I'm not really sure that I understand the second part of your answer.

Comment: parentview.cornerradius=2(custom cell)

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen shot,
i think, your constrains are not properly set.

OR

you can use custom xib as a cell.